# unrecognized selector sent to instance when clicking on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Looking around i can see this type of error has been various from person to person solution wise.

Basically i have a UITableViewController inside a ViewController, inside that tableView is a list of friends pulled from our online database. My goal was to acheive a sliding effect gesture from left to right, i found many sample codes and ended up using [LRSlidingTableViewCell](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRSlidingTableViewCell), at first we tried bringing over the files and calling them appropriately, the cheat code way i presume you would call it. And it threw an exception same as what im getting now. Accept i tried a new method since were going to need to call this sliding effect on 2 different views (seques) and decided to include them in a MyClass that i can call globally, i know the coding we use for calling global variables is solid, we have it working where it outputs us a current user login on every single page view we have. So now that ive discribed my situation. And what im trying to acomplish...

Heres my error code,

```
2013-01-25 13:29:40.397 myappbeta[5496:907] -[UITableViewCell openDrawer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddaacb0
2013-01-25 13:29:40.399 myappbeta[5496:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell openDrawer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddaacb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x39deb2a3 0x33cda97f 0x39deee07 0x39ded531 0x39d44f68 0x123b5 0x32fdf26d 0x33061ea1 0x34be6a6f 0x39dc05df 0x39dc0291 0x39dbef01 0x39d31ebd 0x39d31d49 0x380ff2eb 0x32f712f9 0xd129 0x3759db20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Heres MyClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JBSlidingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIView* _bottomDrawer;
    UIView* _topDrawer;
    UILabel* _titleLabel;
}
// Callback: Called when the bottom drawer is about to be shown. Add subviews here.
- (void)bottomDrawerWillAppear;

// Callback: Called when the bottom drawer has disappeared and is about to be released.
// Release subviews here.
- (void)bottomDrawerDidDisappear;

// Creates the bottom drawer, then opens the top drawer to reveal it.
- (void)openDrawer;

// Closes the top drawer over the bottom drawer, then releases the bottom drawer.
- (void)closeDrawer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* bottomDrawer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* topDrawer;

@end



@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
+ (NSString*)str;
+ (void)setStr:(NSString*)newStr;
+ (void)uploadImg:(UIImage*)img;
@end
```

and now the MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

static NSString* str;

@implementation JBSlidingTableViewCell


@synthesize bottomDrawer = _bottomDrawer;
@synthesize topDrawer = _topDrawer;
@synthesize titleLabel = _titleLabel;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    if (nil != self) {
        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 13, 304, 20)];
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.topDrawer addSubview:self.titleLabel];
        _bottomDrawer = nil;

        // Top drawer
        self.topDrawer = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.topDrawer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.topDrawer];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    _bottomDrawer = nil;
    _topDrawer = nil;
    _titleLabel = nil;
}


- (void)closeDrawer {
    if (self.topDrawer.hidden) {
        CATransition* animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.delegate = self;
        animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        animation.duration = 0.2f;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [self.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        self.contentView.hidden = NO;
        self.topDrawer.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void)openDrawer {
    self.bottomDrawer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self bottomDrawerWillAppear];
    [self insertSubview:self.bottomDrawer belowSubview:self.contentView];

    CATransition* animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    animation.duration = 0.2f;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    self.topDrawer.hidden = YES;
    self.contentView.hidden = YES;
}


- (void)bottomDrawerDidDisappear {
    // Can be overridden by subclasses.
}

- (void)bottomDrawerWillAppear {
    self.bottomDrawer.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    UILabel* bottomDrawerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 13, 304, 20)];
    bottomDrawerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    bottomDrawerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0];
    bottomDrawerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.75];
    bottomDrawerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    bottomDrawerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    bottomDrawerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bottom drawer!%d",rand()];
    [self.bottomDrawer addSubview:bottomDrawerLabel];}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.topDrawer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [self bottomDrawerDidDisappear];
    [self.bottomDrawer removeFromSuperview];
    self.bottomDrawer = nil;
}

@end


@implementation MyClass


+ (NSString*)str {
    return str;
}

+ (void)setStr:(NSString*)newStr {
    if (str != newStr) {
        str = [newStr copy];
    }
}
+ (void)uploadImg:(UIImage*)img {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9);

    NSMutableDictionary *userDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[MyClass str],@"email", nil];
    NSString *returnString;

    NSString *urlString = @"MYURL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *filename = [MyClass str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    //NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"great problem", @"infront of my house",nil] forKeys:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"problem",@"location",nil]];
    NSMutableString *tempVal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(NSString * key in userDict)
    {
        [tempVal appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary];
        [tempVal appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@",key,[userDict objectForKey:key]];
    }

    NSString *postData = [tempVal description];
    //here Webservices is my class name
    [postbody appendData:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if(imageData != nil)
    {
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filetype=\"image/jpeg\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    }

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"requesting upload");

   // NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postbody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSLog(str2);
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];
    NSLog(@"uploading");

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(returnString);
    NSLog(returnString);
}

@end
```

Now here are the files and code to where the view in the storyboard is called.

friendsListTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TBXML.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface friendsListTableViewController: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *friendList;
    TBXML * tbxml;
    NSMutableArray *friends;
    IBOutlet UILabel *friendsFullNames;
    IBOutlet UIImage *imageFile;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@private
    NSIndexPath* _openedCellIndexPath;
    NSArray* _regularCellStrings;
    UITableView* _tableView;
}

    - (IBAction)inviteFriends:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friendList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;



@end
```

and the friendsListTableViewController.m

```
#import "friendsListTableViewController.h"
#import "loginViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface friendsListTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, readonly) JBSlidingTableViewCell* openedCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* openedCellIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray* regularCellStrings;

- (void)closeOpenedCell;
@end

@implementation friendsListTableViewController
@synthesize openedCellIndexPath = _openedCellIndexPath;
@synthesize regularCellStrings = _regularCellStrings;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize friends, friendList;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (nil != self) {
        _openedCellIndexPath = nil;

        self.regularCellStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First default cell", @"Second default cell", nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    _openedCellIndexPath = nil;
    tableView = nil;
}


- (JBSlidingTableViewCell*)openedCell {
    JBSlidingTableViewCell* cell;

    if (nil == self.openedCellIndexPath) {
        cell = nil;
    } else {
        cell = (JBSlidingTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.openedCellIndexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Methods

- (void)closeOpenedCell {
    [self.openedCell closeDrawer];
    self.openedCellIndexPath = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    [self closeOpenedCell];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    friendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    //USED TO CONNECT TO SERVERS XML

    //UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Userid Below :D" message:[MyClass str] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Agains" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //[alert show];
    NSString *someOtherString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MYURL?userid=%@", [MyClass str]];
    //UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Userid Below :D" message:someOtherString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Agains" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //[alert2 show];
        NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someOtherString]];
    tbxml = [[TBXML alloc]initWithXMLData:xmlData];

    //USED FOR LOCAL XML     //PLEASE USE ONLY WHEN IN DEVELOPMENT/TESTING
    //NSString *xmlData = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"friendlist" ofType:@"xml"];
    //NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xmlData];
    //tbxml = [[TBXML alloc]initWithXMLData:data];

    //strings
    // Obtain root element
    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    if (root)
    {
        TBXMLElement * allFriends = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"friend" parentElement:root];
        while (allFriends !=nil)
        {
            TBXMLElement * fname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"fname" parentElement:allFriends];
            NSString *firstName = [TBXML textForElement:fname];
            TBXMLElement * lname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"lname" parentElement:allFriends];
            NSString *lastName = [TBXML textForElement:lname];
            NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            [friendList addObject:fullname];
            allFriends = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"friend" searchFromElement:allFriends];
        }

        //TBXMLElement *fname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"fname" parentElement:elem_PLANT];
    }

}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate + UITableViewDatasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [friendList count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[[JBSlidingTableViewCell alloc] init]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    friendsFullNames = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    friendsFullNames.text = [friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    imageFile = (UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    //imageFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    [self closeOpenedCell];
    [(JBSlidingTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] openDrawer];
    self.openedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
}
/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate


- (IBAction)inviteFriends:(id)sender {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        // Email Subject
        NSString *emailTitle = @"Woot";
        // Email Content
        NSString *messageBody = @"Some HTML Content";
        // To address
        NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"myemail@dress.com"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
        [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Account Found" message:@"You need to add an email account to your device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        // optional - add more buttons:
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add Account"];
        [alert show];
    }

}


- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

In the storyboard its identifier "Cell" is correct, and the tableView that contains the cells is pulling the information correctly from the database perfectly fine.

We are receiving this error when we click the cell, in atempt to test the sliding functionality.

I know its a lot of source code to lok through. But i appreciate any time and effort put into helping me out.

Thanks

Comment: Your error message says: "-[UITableViewCell openDrawer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...". The message `openDrawer` is getting sent to a standard `UITableViewCell`, not a `JBSlidingTableViewCell`. I assume you've got a cell prototype in IB, but that the prototype cell would appear to not have been defined with a custom class of `JBSlidingTableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Is prototype's class set to `JBSlidingTableViewCell`? It seems not.</s> (see i said rubbish here)

In general:

If you are using dynamic prototype cell in storyboard (but you allocate cell subviews programmatically so why you need prototype at all?):

you should create it with just `... = [[[JBSlidingTableViewCell alloc] init];` Then the customizations that you put in your `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` you can put in `awakeFromNib` method (or you can customize cell in storyboard), if you need reuse id one for whole class, then just override `reuseIdentifier` getter, and return id there.

Comment: It was because of my prototype not being set to the JBSlidingTableViewCell like @rob stated in his comment. and how you originally stated bu retracted your answer by saying its rubish... but i'll accept your anyways since there was no other answer provided.